# How to modify how Brackets behaves?

Tags: software-installation

I installed [Brackets](http://www.brackets.io/) (somehow), and now I feel like hacking the hell out of it (to make it better), but now I can't remember how I installed it, or where I installed it to.

How can I find this out?

I *may* have installed it via PPA, with:

```
sudo apt-get install brackets
```

Comment: I should also note that if I use the search function in uh, the Ubuntu equivalent of Windows/File Explorer, I get no results for "brackets" or "Brackets". So I am able to use a program that doesn't exist. Kinda cool, but confusing.

Comment: There are several ways, depending on which GUI or shell or even Ubuntu flavor you are using.  But Linux itself has methods, such as the find command - but you need to use the correct syntax.  It can take a while sometimes, to search the entire filesystem, but the syntax is `find / -iname filename`, where "/" is the starting point (root).  A better version is `find / -iname *bracket* 2>/dev/null`, which will find anything with "bracket", without regard to case, and throw away all the warnings that clutter up the output.

Comment: @MartyFried even better, `locate brackets`.

Comment: @Braiam perhaps you should be more careful next time. You edited my question's title so much that it is unrelated to my original question.

Comment: You should be more careful that such edits are not necessary.  The original had too many interpretations that if I don't edit it I would be voting to close.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to hack on a piece of software, you should not use the binary distribution, but the source distribution. For packages in Ubuntu, you can use `apt-get source packagename`. For instance, in order to get the source code for GEdit, you'll do `apt-get source gedit`. For PPAs that might not work, but you'll get the source from their Launchpad.net page.

You shouldn't really care too much about individual files that comes with a package, because that's what the package system is for, but if you do want to list all the files that were installed with a package, you can use `dpkg -L packagename`. In your case, that should be `dpkg -L brackets`.

None of those commands require root permissions, so you should not prefix them with sudo.

Comment: Even if `apt-get source` works it's generally not what you'd want for developing though. The source code there is generally way out of date - instead you'll want to find the repository of the team and get the current version from there - that also allows you to actually contribute to the project. This can be found [here](https://github.com/adobe/brackets) if I got the right project.

Comment: It is not out of date if you want to change something in the version you're using.

Answer (score 2):

To search for a program through terminal `locate` is generally the best way to go about this.

Then you can just type `locate brackets` and you should be given a list of everything relating to that word.

Note that the database must be up to date. It's usually updated daily by anacron, but to manually update it, run `sudo updatedb` before using `locate`.

Comment: Better to simply do a database lookup using dpkg -L.

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad Not if it wasn't installed by the package manager. (The questioner is unsure.)